# How to create a left-side tree menu as a template in other pages in Notion

Tags: notion

I want to create a left-side tree menu on all my pages. I am using a Wiki template.  My main page is pretty simple. It has a left-side menu and content:
[image: Main page]

As you can see it has Code Reviews page. But Code Reviews page has subpage and subpage has its own subpage. Here is page structure on notion desktop app:
[image: Page in Notion app]

I want to show menu with this structure on all pages. For example when I go to other page, I want to see this menu. How can I do that?